# Is there a biglm equivalent for coxph?

Tags: r, survival, large-data

I am trying fit a Cox Proportional Hazard model with coxph with a cmoputer of 12GB of RAM. It keeps running out of memory. Is there a biglm equivalent of coxph?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe take a look at the [DatABEL](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DatABEL/) package. I know it is used in genomic studies with large data that may be stored on the HD instead of RAM. From what I read in the help file, you can then apply different kind of model, including survival model.

Comment: Looks interesting, thanks.  I have similar problem to the OP trying penalized + coxph on a big data set, wonder if this helps.